# Uniform Distribution - Find the Min Value

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Statistics Question

Prompt: Penguins appear warmer than their background (remember penguins are mammals).
Suppose that on a given island, thermal values for a colony of penguins are uniformly distributed with a maximum thermal value of 18 C.
It has been reported that 20% of colonies report a thermal value of at least 15 C.

Based on this information, determine the minimum thermal value for colonies on the Island.

My work:

(18-15) 3 (for the 20% of the data)
3 * 5 = 15
18 - x = 15 --> x = 3.

Therefore the min temperature of the thermal value is 3 degrees C.

Comment: Correct. In R, where `qunif` is uniform quantile function (inverse CDF). code: `qunif(.8, 3, 18)` returns $15,$ so the 80th percentile of $\mathsf{Unif}(3, 18)$ is indeed $15.$ Also, `1 - punif(15, 3, 18)` returns probability  $0.2,$ as it should. where `punif` is unform CDF.